# Update table by case ORA-01722 Invalid Number

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to update a table's column based on the value of of two other columns.

For some reason, I am getting ORA-01722: invalid number

```
UPDATE TableT SET 
   Col = (CASE when PER in ('1234','2134','2314','3214') AND TYPE = 4 then '4' 
                     when PER in ('34','104','1004') AND TYPE = 4 then '35' 
                     when PER in ('124','1204','2014') AND TYPE = 4  then '36'
               ELSE 'Missing'  
END);
```

Comment: which is the datatype of `col` field?

Comment: `Col` is type `NUMBER(10)`

Comment: Then you should do what @Mureinik said below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this statement  can fail with ORA-01722 is if `Col` is a numeric column. `'4'`, `'35'` and `'36'` can be automatically converted to a number. However, if none of the `case` conditions are met, and you end up evaluating the `else` branch, it will return the string `Missing` that cannot be converted to a number.

One way to deal with it could be to use `null`, which was designed to signify a missing value instead:

```
UPDATE TableT SET 
   Col = (CASE when PER in ('1234','2134','2314','3214') AND TYPE = 4 then 4 
                     when PER in ('34','104','1004') AND TYPE = 4 then 35 
                     when PER in ('124','1204','2014') AND TYPE = 4  then 36
               ELSE NULL  
          END);
```

Comment: `Col` is type `NUMBER(10)`.

Comment: It lets me run the statement without error but it updates all the rows, which is not true.

Comment: nevermind, I got it I need to put the where clause outside. Thanks for help.